# Can idDelta and idRangeOffset both be non zero in TrueType fonts?

Tags: fonts, truetype, opentype

Is it possible that in cmap format 4 of a TrueType font that idDelta and idRangeOffset of a segment are both non-zero? And if so, why?

Why would you need to add idDelta if the glyph index taken from glyphIndexArray can be whatever the font manufacturer wants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/otspec140/cmap#format-4-segment-mapping-to-delta-values, this would not make sense, as an `idRangeOffset` that is non-zero means the parser needs to consult the `glyphIdArray`, which does not involve the `idDelta` value in any way, whereas an `idRangeOffset:0` means that the segment's glyph id is based on adding the `idDelta` to the character code offset, and does *not* use the `glyphIdArray`.

So to answer your question: "Why would you need to add idDelta if the glyph index taken from glyphIndexArray can be whatever the font manufacturer wants?", the reason is "because that's not what happens at all".

Quoting the spec:

> If the idRangeOffset value for the segment is not 0, the mapping of character codes relies on glyphIdArray. The character code offset from startCode is added to the idRangeOffset value. This sum is used as an offset from the current location within idRangeOffset itself to index out the correct glyphIdArray value. This obscure indexing trick works because glyphIdArray immediately follows idRangeOffset in the font file. The C expression that yields the glyph index is:
>
> ```
> *(idRangeOffset[i]/2 + (c - startCount[i]) + &idRangeOffset[i])
> ```
>
> The value c is the character code in question, and i is the segment index in which c appears. If the value obtained from the indexing operation is not 0 (which indicates missingGlyph), idDelta[i] is added to it to get the glyph index. The idDelta arithmetic is modulo 65536.
>
> If the idRangeOffset is 0, the idDelta value is added directly to the character code offset (i.e. idDelta[i] + c) to get the corresponding glyph index. Again, the idDelta arithmetic is modulo 65536.

And while the spec assumes you know how C works, folks these days don't: the `*` at the front means that we're computing a byte offset, relative to the start of the file. The `&` means "the memory location of this thing" (although in this case that means byte offset into our font file), so we're adding a number (`idRangeOffset[i]/2 + (c - startCount[i])`) to the byte location of the i<sup>th</sup> range offset (`&idRangeOffset[i]`), which gives us a new offset. If we start reading the font bytes starting at the byte offset corresponding to that number, we'll be at the correct spot to read in our glyph id.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  A non-zero idRangeOffset identifies an element of glyphIdArray from which to obtain the glyph index.  Note the obscure wording.  If that element contains 0, then the glyph ID is 0, the missing glyph.  Otherwise, one adds idDelta to the value in the element to obtain the glyph ID.  This allows different segments to use the same part of the glyphIdArray with different results, resulting in a more compact subtable.

There is one issue though.  In June 2020, I discovered that iPhones 6 and 7, running iOS 12.4.6, would assume that idDelta was zero if idRangeOffset was non-zero.  The subtable worked properly with Windows and HarfBuzz renderers.  I don't know whether the interpretation is fixed in iOS 12.5.5, nor the MacOS situation.  That such a bug could persist so long shows how rarely this optimisation has been applied - it is only available in unusual situations.